# RFID: PN532 with Mifare Plus SE

Tags: esp32, rfid, mifare, pn532

I'm trying to figure out how to properly communicate with Mifare PLUS SE card in order to make it SL3 protected. It uses AES authentication in order to read / write data.

Unfortunately, there is not much open info to use.

I'm looking for a way of how to convert Mifare PLUS SE with SL1 to SL3 using PN532 reader with ESP32 (Nodemcu).

I understand that I would need to send raw commands via this reader, but I have no clue of commands themselves and their sequence.

Could someone share their experience of using this type of reader to use the card over SL3 mode?